# Задача на Prolog GNU

Tags: prolog

Здравствуйте!

Помогите доделать задачку на Prolog GNU.

> Написать функцию, выполняющую над числовым одноуровневым списком следующую операцию. Причем последовательное возведение в степень выполняется справа налево.
>
> (A B C ...) —> A^B^C...

Дошел до следующего:

```
//  функция а - возведение в степень. работает корректно.
a(A, 1, A):-!. 
a(_, 0, 1):-!.
a(A, N, Y):- NN is N-1, a(A, NN, R), Y is R*A.

// функция b - обработка списка. работает криво, проблема, так понимаю, в третей строке. Получается возведение только последних двух чисел, 
т.е для списка (2, 3, 2, 4) будет только 2^4.
b([], _):- !.
b([H|[HH|[]]], X):- a(H, HH, Y), X is Y, !.
b([H|T], X):- b(T, X), a(H, X, K).
```

Пишу по аналогии программы на Lisp, которую писал ранее, может, поможет вам разобраться:

```
(defun ^ (x n) 
   (if (= N 0) 1
   (if (< N 0)
       (/ 1 (^ x (- 0 N)))
       (* x (^ x (- N 1))) )
) )

(defun A (L) 
   (cond
       ((null L) nil)
       ((null (cddr L)) (^ (car L) (cadr L))) 
       (T (^ (car L)(A (cdr L))))
) )
```

Спасибо за помощь.

- Задача решена.

Как и говорил, проблема была в третей строке функции b.

Нужно было внимательнее разбираться с переменными:

```
b([H|T], X):- b(T, K), a(H, K, G), X is G.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача решена.
Как и говорил, проблема была в третей строке функции `b`.

Нужно было внимательнее разбираться с переменными:

```
b([H|T], X):- b(T, K), a(H, K, G), X is G.
```